# NHibernate QueryOver with component list

Tags: nhibernate-criteria

I have classes as follows:

```
public class File {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

And Customer.Files is setup as a bag of components (not entities).  Is there any way I can make a QueryOver that will return a customer who has a file with a given ID using QueryOver syntax in NHibernate?

Comment: I figured out how to do this with HQL, but I need CriteriaOver syntax:  select c from Customer as c, elements(c.Files) as a where a.Id = :id

Answer (score 1):

it should be as easy as

```
session.QueryOver<Customer>()
    .JoinQueryOver<File>(c => c.Files)
        .Where(f => f.Id == id)
    .List();
```